# expo FileSystem overwrite exsting image

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to modify the metadata of an existing image. To do this, I am reading the image as a base64 string using `await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(imageUri, { encoding: "base64" })`, and then modifying the metadata using the piexifjs library. However, when I try to write the modified image back to the file system using `await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(imageUri, base64Code[1], { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 })`, I get an error saying that the location is not writable.

One potential solution is to delete the original image and then write the modified image as a new file. However, this is not ideal because it prompts the user on Android devices to confirm the modification every time the metadata is edited.

Is there a better way to overwrite an existing image with a new base64 string without deleting the original file?

Comment: can you share your `imageUri` format?

Comment: It's the fileuri with "///". It's from Expo Media Library